# Strange behaviour in rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing tests with my RoR application. my static_pages_spec.rb

```
    # encoding: utf-8

require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Giripedia') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }
    it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home' }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Yardım') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help')) }
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Hakkımızda') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us')) }
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'İletişim') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Contact')) }
  end
end
```

and in my spec/support/utilites.rb file

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end
```

If I change base_title = "Giripedia forum ". The tests fail and give me errors :

```
1) Static pages Home page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }
       expected css "title" with text "Giripedia forum" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Help page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help')) }
       expected css "title" with text "Giripedia forum | Help" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages About page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us')) }
       expected css "title" with text "Giripedia forum | About Us" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Static pages Contact page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Contact')) }
       expected css "title" with text "Giripedia forum | Contact" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why does the change in base_title starts to fail in tests?

Comment: Did you change the `title` in your web pages, too?

Comment: The titles did not change. I only changed the base_title. I use helper method for the tests.

Comment: I found my mistake, I did not change my real application_helper.rb. I only changed the specs file. It took me one hour to see the mistake.

Comment: When the system allows you to finally answer your own question, could you please write up something nice to document what the end solution was? It will probably be helpful for someone else in the future.

Comment: Thanks sarnold, i am learning the stackoverflow habbits yet.

Answer (score 1):

I could manage to find my mistake here. May be this would help others.

I only changed base_title in spec file. But I was supposed to change the base_title which is belonging the app/helper which was tested.

I know , I should read the test log well.